# RowValidating doesn't prevent leaving an invalid row

Tags: winforms, validation, datagridview, row

I have bunch of textboxes bound to a datagridview. I want to prevent users from leaving a row if invalid input is entered.

I tried both the RowLeave and RowValidating events. They both give me the data row user is entering, not the old one. Therefore, in the RowValidating events, when I set the event.cancel=true, it does not revert back to the old row.

Basically I need a way to capture the row the user is trying to leave, and I am not able to do it with any of the those events.

Thanks!!

Edit : I guess a silly way to do it is via rowEnter event. I imagine I can accomplish what I want with that, but all the purpose of those fancy events are lost...

Update : I think the problem is with the data binding. I can see the underlying datarow is locked but that is not reflected in the textboxes. Yikes..

Answer (score 0):

Try `CellValidating`, I know this used to work for me.

Comment: unfortunately for me, CellValidating is not even firing when row is changed...Maybe something to do with how I data bind the datagridview ?

Comment: Hmmm, off the top of my head I cannot remember if something else is required in order to get it to work.  I'll have to have a look tonight.